# Anyway to "wait 1 second" in minecraft forge 1.12.2?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

i have tried to "wait 1 second" in minecraft forge and i use "Thread" to do it.
But i got this error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:218)
    at io.github.bloodnighttw.WaitAndReplaceBlock.run(WaitAndReplaceBlock.java:22)
```

i have tried to use `world.scheduleBlockUpdate(......)` to do it,but anything happened after i break block.

And this is my code,there have three class.

`ExampleMod.java`

```
package io.github.bloodnighttw;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import io.github.bloodnighttw.event.Event;

@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, name = ExampleMod.NAME, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod
{
    public static final String MODID = "nothing";
    public static final String NAME = "Bang!";
    public static final String VERSION = "3.0";

    private static Logger logger;

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event)
    {
        logger = event.getModLog();
        logger.info("Bang");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        // some example code
        logger.info("DIRT BLOCK >> {}", Blocks.DIRT.getRegistryName());

        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new Event());
    }
 }
```

`Event.java`

```
package io.github.bloodnighttw.event;

import io.github.bloodnighttw.WaitAndReplaceBlock;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentString;
import net.minecraftforge.event.world.BlockEvent.BreakEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;


public class Event {

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void breakBlockEvent(final BreakEvent e) {
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(new TextComponentString(e.getState().toString()+"222222"));
        BlockPos a = e.getPos();
        new WaitAndReplaceBlock(a,e).start();

    }
}
```

`WaitAndReplaceBlock.java`

```
package io.github.bloodnighttw;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.event.world.BlockEvent;

public class WaitAndReplaceBlock extends Thread{

    BlockPos a;
    BlockEvent.BreakEvent e ;

    public WaitAndReplaceBlock(BlockPos a, BlockEvent.BreakEvent e){
        this.a = a ;
        this.e = e ;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            wait(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
            interruptedException.printStackTrace();
        }
        World world = e.getWorld();
        world.setBlockState(a, Blocks.BEDROCK.getDefaultState());

    }
}
```

i have tried to google it,but everything i search is too old to be use in 1.12.2 or it is not a solution to me,so i decided to ask in stackoverflow.

---

**Edit:**
This is the code that i used `world.scheduleBlockUpdate(......)`
Only `Event.java` have some change.

`Event.java`
    package io.github.bloodnighttw.event;

```
import io.github.bloodnighttw.WaitAndReplaceBlock;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentString;
import net.minecraftforge.event.world.BlockEvent.BreakEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;


public class Event {

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void breakBlockEvent(final BreakEvent e) {
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(new TextComponentString(e.getState().toString()+"222222"));
        BlockPos a = e.getPos();
        //new WaitAndReplaceBlock(a,e).start();

        e.getWorld().scheduleBlockUpdate(a,e.getState().getBlock(),10,1000000);

    }

}
```

And this is what i said "Nothing happened".
Video: https://youtu.be/tZMIRHDUnV4

Comment: make the method `synchronized`.

Comment: Threads are the wrong way to do this. `scheduleBlockUpdate` is right. Please post the code that used it, as well as a more detailed explanation of what happened with it.

Comment: Ok,later i will edit it and post .

Comment: because i'm not in home and now i can't use computer. and just to need to go home . and thx all of u that answer my question.

Comment: Ok i have edited it.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn your way can;t stop  throwing exception expection,but can't replace block QAQ.

Comment: My comment was for a general `IllegalMonitorStateException` - happens if you don't sync on the lock.

Comment: Okay, you scheduled a block update, but you don't have any code to do something when a block update happens.

Comment: using ``world.notifyBlocksOfNeighborChange(......)`` in my program?